# When I hover over a div a new div appears ontop of the div causing the overlap to flicker when I move the mouse

Tags: css

Here is a link to my problem [http://jsfiddle.net/xb3qkwpp/3/a](http://jsfiddle.net/xb3qkwpp/3/)

When you hover over the green area it starts to flicker when I move the mouse. I am thinking it is z-index but I have set the z-index for the class and ids and it didnt work or maybe I am doing it incorrectly.

html:

```
<div id="first_area_max" class="first_area">
      <div class="first_area_wrapper">
        <h2>
          FIRST
        </h2>
        <h1>
          foo
        </h1>
        <p class="tk-proxima-nova">
          “I started out in concrete whenI was 18 years old and havebeen at this business for almost20 years. Our team isprofessional, knowledgeable,and will go full throttle everyday for our clients.”
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="second_area_max" class="second_area">
      <div class="second_area_wrapper">
        <h2>
          SECOND
        </h2>
        <h1>
          foo
        </h1>
        <p class="tk-proxima-nova">
          “I started out in concrete whenI was 18 years old and havebeen at this business for almost20 years. Our team isprofessional, knowledgeable,and will go full throttle everyday for our clients.”
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="third_area_max" class="third_area">
      <div class="third_area_wrapper">
        <h2>
          THIRD
        </h2>
        <h1>
          foo
        </h1>
        <p class="tk-proxima-nova">
          “I started out in concrete whenI was 18 years old and havebeen at this business for almost20 years. Our team isprofessional, knowledgeable,and will go full throttle everyday for our clients.”
        </p>
      </div>
```

css:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black; }

h1, h2, h3 {
  font-weight: normal; }

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit; }

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0; }

.no-padding {
  padding: 0; }

.no-margin {
  margin: 0; }

.clear {
  clear: both; }

.first_boss {
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0.7;
}


.second_boss {
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.third_boss {
    background: green;
    opacity: 0.7;
}


.first_page, .second_page, .third_page, .fifth_page {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 800px;
  max-width: 1300px; }

.first_page, .second_page, .third_page, .fifth_page {
  min-width: 1000px;
  background-position: center center;
  margin: 0 auto; }


.fifth_page {
  background-image: image-url("fifth_page.jpg");
  z-index: -1;
  z-index: -1; }
  .fifth_page h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 40px; }
  .fifth_page h1, .fifth_page h2 {
    font-family: 'mohaveregular'; }
  .fifth_page p {
    width: 230px;
    line-height: 2em;
    float: right; }

.first_area, .second_area, .third_area {
  color: white;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  float: right;
  background-image: image-url("owner_bg.png"); }
  .first_area p, .second_area p, .third_area p {
    width: 230px;
    line-height: 2em;
    float: right; }

#first_area_max, #second_area_max, #third_area_max {
  margin-right: -850px;
  z-index: 1; }

#first_mouse:hover ~ #first_area_max, #second_mouse:hover ~ #second_area_max, #third_mouse:hover ~ #third_area_max {
  right: 1000px;
  width: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  overflow: visible; }

.first_boss, .second_boss, .third_boss {
  float: left;
  height: 800px;
  width: 33%;
  z-index: -2; }

.first_area_wrapper, .second_area_wrapper, .third_area_wrapper {
  margin-right: 70px; }

#third_area_max {
  z-index: 1000; }


.text-area {
  padding: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  text-transform: uppercase; }


.clear {
  clear: both; }
```

Comment: you should probably post your css code here as it is a css related question (dont rely on external links to explain your question)

Comment: Ok I will do that now...

Comment: i actually dont know the answer to this, but hopefully with a better formatted question and all the info right here, someone could help you out. good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hover on the div you put on top of it as well. Because of the appearing div you lose focus on the first one, causing your hover state to switch rapidly.

```css
.div1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.div2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
.div1:hover ~ .div2,
.div2:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```